# How do I set a computed local variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a `tf.json` file that declares a bunch of local variables.  One of the variables is a array of complex objects like so:

```
{
  "locals": [
    {
      "ordered_cache_behaviors": [
        {
          "path_pattern": "/poc-app-angular*",
          "s3_target": "dev-ui-static",
          "ingress": "external"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what I want to do... instead of declaring the variable `ordered_cache_behaviors` statically in my file I want this to be a computed value.  I will get this configuration from a `S3` bucket and set the value here.  So the value statically will only be an empty array `[]` that I will append to with a script after getting the data from `S3`.

This logic needs to execute each time before a `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`.  What is the best way to do this?  I am assuming I need to use a Provisioner to fire off a script?  If so how do I then set the local variable here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cache configuration data can be JSON-formatted, you may be able to use the [s3_bucket_object datasource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket_object) plus the [jsondecode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsondecode.html) function as an alternative approach:

Upload your cache configuration data to the `poc-app-cache-config` bucket as `cache-config.json`, and then use the following to have Terraform download that file from S3 and parse it into your local `ordered_cache_behaviors` variable:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "cache_configuration" {
  bucket = "poc-app-cache-config"
  key    = "cache-config.json" # JSON-formatted cache configuration map
}

...

locals {
  ordered_cache_behaviors = jsondecode(aws_s3_bucket_object.cache_configuration.body)
}
```